# Input formula for 2 switching sine-waves (Heaviside eq'n)?

Tags: filter, switching

If we have 2 signal generators
1: \$\ 2sin(2 \omega t)\$
2: \$\ 3sin(5 \omega t)\$
being input to a selector switch that switches between the two continuous inputs every 0.5 seconds being sent to a low pass filter,

what would be my input equation to this filter?

So far, I have a rough idea that it would involve the Heaviside step function and represent something along the lines of:
\$\ 2sin(2\omega t)[U(t)-U(t-0.5)]+3sin(5 \omega t)[U(t-0.5)-U(1.0)]+2sin(2 \omega t)[U(t-1.0)-U(t-1.5) . . .etc \$

Is this about right?

Is there a general equation for such a system rather than writing a massive Heaviside equation?

Comment: Is switching synchronous with zero crossings on both sinewaves?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you are describing is a frequency modulated waveform. Every 0.5 seconds the frequency changes instantaneously from 2\$\omega\$ to 5\$\omega\$ and back again. As RF engineers know, a carrier signal that is modulated by a sinewave produces an infinite bandwidth but you can make decent approximations even if the modulating signal is complex audio - after all FM radios work just fine last time I checked.

The problem with your signal is that you are modulating with a square wave and a square wave has infinite spectral content so, not only are you wanting to create a signal that will have infinite bandwidth (due to modulation but can be approximated to a finite banwidth), you are using a modulation signal that has infinite bandwidth.

So if you want a perfect answer it's going to be an infinite fourier series (the square wave) with each term enclosed within the standard formula for FM.

Basically this means there are no simple math tricks to express the signal mathematically, heavyside or not.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I suspected as much. Thanks for your answer.